# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I have this code:

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter text");
StringBuilder forward = new StringBuilder("");
StringBuilder backward = new StringBuilder("");
int f = 0;
int b = input.length();


while(f < input.length()) {

    while(input.charAt(f) > 63) {

        forward.append(input.charAt(f));
        f++;

    }

    f++;
} 

System.out.println(forward);
```

although program is not finished, it already throws an exception here. It says:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5 ( Range depends on, how many character i enter )
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)

Strange thing is that i yesterday worked on similar code and it worked perfectly, and it was practical the same.

I already searched stack forums and docs oracle but i only found that this exception is thrown when is index equal the size of the string ( for charAt method ).

So still it seems to be the problem right here but i can't find it.

```
while(input.charAt(f) > 63)
```

EDIT:

Why is that code not working? Again its throwing same exception as above?

```
while(b > 0) {

        if(input.charAt(b) > 63) {

            backward.append(input.charAt(b));

        }

        b--;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of `f` can exceed the length of the string here:

```
while (input.charAt(f) > 63) {
    forward.append(input.charAt(f));

    // This next line might increase f past the end of the string.
    f++;
}
```

Try this instead:

```
while (f < input.length()) {

    char c = input.charAt(f);
    if (c > 63) {
        forward.append(c);
    }

    f++;
}
```

The second version always checks `f < input.length()` before attempting to access `input.charAt(f)`.

Comment: Thank you. Your code worked! But i still don't know why my code i wrote yesterday worked. And it had 2 while loops also. ( it also looped through characters in certain word. While loop was practical the same ).

Comment: @FirefoxxPwnass: Your code will work in some but not all cases. It may be yesterday that you got "lucky" and tested it only on cases where it worked.

Comment: It seems programming is a relative thing ;D Thank you for your answer again. I learned something today ;D